# Numpy: read column major structured array from memory address

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

I got a C library storing its results in memory as a structure of arrays and returning a pointer to it. I'd like to create a writeable numpy array using this memory. Unfortunately, the arrays don't have a common type making this rather difficult.

For a classic array of structures, I'd create a equivalent ctypes Structure, init it via `from_address()` and pass that to `numpy.ctypeslib.as_array()`. Doing this with a structure of array results in a zero dimensional array, meaning I can't slice it.

Since this basically is just column major instead of row major layout, I hoped that I could just pass a `F_CONTINOUS` flag to as_array, but it does not have that option. I looked into NumPy's array interface protocol and to me it seems that this use case is not supported, as I can't provide strides for `descr`.

Is there a way to create a structured array in column-major order or do I need to create a separate array for each column?

I only found one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719324/fortran-ordered-column-major-numpy-structured-array-possible), but in the answer it was only suggested that it *may* work with advanced dtypes, which I couldn't confirm.

Comment: Could you return a dictionary of NumPy arrays, one Numpy array for each array in your struct? That could be converted into a Pandas dataframe in a zero-copy way, and Pandas has strong support for heterogeneous types.

Comment: That's a great idea. Haven't thought about using Pandas, since I'm not that familiar with it, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: A dataframe can be composed from Series.  Each series is a separate numpy array (along with an index array).  I doubt if it provides any memory use advantage over a list of such arrays (or equivalently an object dtype array.)